# Uncaught Error at function google script and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this html application which will look for a certain ID number then it will populate the field in the userform. Once I click the button Update Data, I am hoping that it will update the specific row values in the google sheet, but I always end up getting `Uncaught at updateProfile (fcn:81)`. "(fcn:81)" end up to be  `var newDataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).setValues(...`

Here is my javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("updatebtn").addEventListener("click", updateAppProfile);

//----------------------  UPDATE PROFILE  ---------------------------------//   
   function updateAppProfile(){

     var upProfile = document.getElementById("profileNum").value;

     if(upProfile.length === 6){
        var myNewData = {};

        myNewData.profnum = document.getElementById("profileNum").value;
        myNewData.firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        myNewData.middleName = document.getElementById("mname").value;
        myNewData.lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        myNewData.appsex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
        myNewData.civStat = document.getElementById("cstatus").value;
        myNewData.citizen = document.getElementById("citizenship").value;
        myNewData.birthdate = document.getElementById("bdate").value;


    //  console.log(myNewData);
    //  alert("OK");
        google.script.run.updateMyProfile(upProfile,myNewData);

     } 
     else{
     alert("invalid Profile Number");
     }   
   }

    </script>
```

Here is my google app script function:

```
function updateMyProfile(upProfile,myNewData){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");

  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dJoin = data.join().split(",");
  var myPnum = dJoin.indexOf(upProfile);

  if (myPnum > -1){
    var newDataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).setValues([[myNewData.profnum,
                 myNewData.firstName,
                 myNewData.middleName,
                 myNewData.lastName,
                 myNewData.appsex,
                 myNewData.civStat,
                 myNewData.citizen,
                 myNewData.birthdate
                 ]]);
  } else {
    Logger.log("unknown data")
  }

}
```

I don't know what to do since when I test the data on the google script side only it work. But when I used the whole program it ends up in that error. I hope anyone can help. Thank you in advance. I will really appreciate your answers. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your function in a try catch block in order to debug and find the precise error.

- `[Try / Catch][1]`

Besides that:

`var newDataRow = = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn())` is not as flexible as actually using values from the array you are placing into the row. So rather use the following syntax:

`var outputRowArray = [ myNewData.firstName, myNewData.middleName, "etc…" ]` 
and then use its length to determine the range like so:

`var newDataRow = ws.getRange( myPnum + 1, 1, 1, outputRowArray.length )`

And you currently have a Array inside of an Array inside of `setValues()`, but since you are only adding 1 row, 1 array should be used, ie 1 row = 1 array.